# Routes not working in react-router

Tags: typescript, react-router, electron

I could easily be doing something wrong that I'm not seeing, but I've tried three methods and neither works...

I have a TypeScript Electron (this is irrelevant) app using `react-redux`, `react-router`, `react-router-dom`, and `redux-observable`.  I don't think most of that is germane, but I cannot get my routes to update...

There are three methods I am aware of that can get one access to `history.push`.

- Grabbing it from `context`.  *I am aware that this is bad.*
- Exporting history when I create it and before I import it.  (Not a fan of this, it does not seem *idiomatic*)
- Utilizing `withRouter` and the `RouteComponentProps` interface.

The first method, is *unstable* and seems hacky.  The latter two both result in the same problem.  A location change event does indeed occur, but because the `push` fail and I'm doing the location change when the `props` change (I do not like this solution, per se, but *something* will be listening to the state update whether it is a "Container Component" or not) it goes into an infinite loop (well until the router just gives up) because the route *never* actually updates.

E.g. I see this in the `redux-logger`:

```
{
  type: "@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE", 
  payload: {
   hash:"",
   pathname:"/home"
   ...
  }
  ...
}
```

That is correct, but it *never* actually changes the routes.

Here is my `Routes.tsx` file:

```
export default () => (
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
    </Switch>
  </App>
);
```

Which is pulled into `index.tsx` like so:

```
render(
  <AppContainer>
    <Root store={store} history={history} />
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

if ((module as any).hot) {
  (module as any).hot.accept('./containers/Root', () => {
    const NextRoot = require('./containers/Root').default;
    render(
      <AppContainer>
        <NextRoot store={store} history={history} />
      </AppContainer>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  });
}
```

And, for grins, here is the component that is trying to fire a route change, in this case when the user has authenticated:

```
interface Props { }

interface InjectedProps extends RouteComponentProps<InjectedProps>{
  auth: AuthState
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState): Props => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export class LoginPage extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<InjectedProps>> {
  constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<InjectedProps>) {
    super(props);
  }

  injectedProps(): InjectedProps {
    return this.props as InjectedProps;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps: InjectedProps) {
    if(newProps.auth.authenticated) {
     this.props.history.push('/home');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Login />
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginPage));
```

Granted, I am still getting used to TS/Redux as a whole (and this perhaps is an *anti-pattern* of sorts), but I've never had problems using `push` in a plain old React web app.

*If you have any other advice about better structuring such an app, I am all ears.  Ideally, I want to have an action creator fire off such navigational changes so I can keep components lightweight.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, the fix was *very* simple.

I just had to flip the routes.  I don't totally understand why that worked, which is troubling.

```
export default () => (
  <App>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/" component={LoginPage} />
    </Switch>
  </App>
);
```

Comment: The `exact path=` pattern works too... what I didn't realize was that `"/"` and `"/home"` are subset matches.  See https://gist.github.com/siakaramalegos/df4620c52e829f6107c75d5c3f0ad7f5#gistcomment-2151832